# PyCharm fails to add interpreter when docker container has ENTRYPOINT set

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

In PyCharm we are adding a Python Interpreter from a docker container. The docker container has a default ENTRYPOINT set. Using PyCharm 2022.2.1.

Go to: `File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> Add Interpreter -> On Docker`

**Step 1/3**: Select `Pull` and enter the image `username/image:latest`

**Step 2/3**: Next pulls successfully

**Step 3/3**: Select the system python interpreter
Click Create

At this point, we see an error `Python interpreter process exited with a non-zero code 1`, and the error text shows that the `ENTRYPOINT` for the container was executed and errored out.

Is there a way to add a docker container to PyCharm that has a default ENTRYPOINT set? This didn't seem to be a problem in older versions of PyCharm that we configured with this same image.

Comment: What exactly is the `ENTRYPOINT`?  Do you have the image's Dockerfile, and is there any diagnostic output showing how exactly PyCharm is launching the container?

Comment: I'm working with @mirella on this, the `ENTRYPOINT` is defined in the `Dockerfile` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). It's the main command that's executed when running the container. It's currently set to `python somescript.py`. When PyCharm is adding the Python Interpreter it's clearly running this command. The error output clearly shows that `somescript.py` is run and errors out. The error is because we didn't volume map in a credentials file, however, that's a setting for the Run Configuration, not when you add an interpreter, thus our confusion.